# A question on the Hecke L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

For a Hecke L-function, if all of the local eigenvalues are roots of unity, is it an Artin L-function?

Comment: Wikipedia tells you: "In mathematics, a Hecke L-function may refer to:
(i) an L-function of a modular form, (ii) an L-function of a Hecke character." Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whatever your answer to my question in comment, the answer to the title question is yes. Take the case of the $L$-function attached to a modular form $f$, which we assume an eigenform for almost all Hecke operators (since otherwise there is no decomposition of the L-function into Euler product and the phrase "local eigenvalues" has no meaning.)

By Deligne, we know then that the local eigenvalues at $p$ for almost every $p$ are Weil numbers, more precisely they are algebraic numbers whose every embedding in $\mathbb C$ has absolute values $p^{(k-1)/2}$ where $k$ is the weight of your modular form (cf. the last corollary of this [link](http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~t-saito/talk/eepr.pdf) for instance). If just one of those eigenvalue is a root of unity, this already forces $k=1$, in which case we know by Deligne-Serre that the Galois representation attached to $f$ has finite image, that is that $L(f,s)$ is an Artin $L$-function.

Comment: An Hecke L-function might also be associated to a Hecke-Maass form of weight $0$, in which case I don't think we know how to answer the question.

Comment: @Denis, yes. The notion of Hecke $L$-function is hopelessly ambiguous.

Comment: Indeed! (Not to mention the perverse possibility of the L-function of a holomorphic form, normalized so that the critical line is at 1/2...)